# Azure Automation unable to unlink a schedule "The schedule couldn't be unlinked from the runbook"

Tags: azure-automation

I am unable to unlink a schedule from a runbook.
I have a run book that is attached to an existing schedule(the schedule already had another runbook). And when I try to unlink it gives error. This is happening in one environment(ACC). But in PRD and DEV the notebook in the situation unlinked successfully. How to fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was because of the Delete lock on resource group. A proper error message would have helped. If we try to delete a schedule then it gives the correct error message that it is locked.